# footer implementation in fluid layout

Tags: html, css, layout, fluid-layout

I'm having problem in implementing the footer for my website.
I have taken two `<ul>` lists in the `inner_footer` as you can see in the code below. But as I zoom in, the `<ul>` list in the div element is not visible. It seems a float problem, but I'm not able to figure out what's wrong with it.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="grid_16">
    <div class="footer">
        <div class="inner_footer">
            <ul>
                <li>Some content</li>
            </ul>
        <div>
            <ul>
                <li><a>Link 1</a></li>
                <li><a>Link 2</a></li>
                <li><a>Link 3</a></li>
                <li><a>Link 4</a></li>
                <li><a>Link 5</a></li>
                <li>Copyrights</li> 
            </ul>   
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.footer {
    height:105px;
    position:relative;
    top:0;
    width:100%;
  }
.inner_footer {
    background:url(../images/layout_img/nav.jpg) 0 center repeat-x;
    font-size:12px;
    border-radius:4px;
    position:relative;
    width:inherit;
    height:31px;
    margin:0 auto;
}
.inner_footer ul {
    margin:0;
}
.inner_footer ul li {
    color:#FFF;
    font-family:calibri;
    font-size:13px;
    list-style-type:none;
    line-height:31px;
    text-decoration:none;
    padding:0 10px;
}
.inner_footer ul li a img {
    margin:2px 0 0 20px;
}
.inner_footer ul li a {
    color:#FFF;
    float:left;
    font-family:calibri;
    font-size:13px;
    list-style-type:none;
    line-height:31px;
    text-decoration:none;
    padding:0 10px;
}
.inner_footer div {
    float:right;
}
.inner_footer div ul li a {
    color:#FFF;
    float:left;
    font-family:calibri;
    font-size:13px;
    list-style-type:none;
    line-height:31px;
    text-decoration:none;
    padding:0 10px;
}
.inner_footer div ul li {
    color:#FFF;
    float:left;
    font-family:calibri;
    font-size:13px;
    list-style-type:none;
    line-height:31px;
    text-decoration:none;
    padding:0 10px;
}
```

Comment: i think u want this http://jsfiddle.net/V9LVW/

Comment: what if i wanted the content and the five links on the same red footer?? i have edited the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the problem is in your html code. You forgot to close a div element. The code should become:

```
<div class="grid_16">
    <div class="footer">
        <div class="inner_footer">
            <ul>
                <li>Some content</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div>
            <ul>
                <li><a>Link 1</a></li>
                <li><a>Link 2</a></li>
                <li><a>Link 3</a></li>
                <li><a>Link 4</a></li>
                <li><a>Link 5</a></li>
                <li>Copyrights</li> 
            </ul>   
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: yeah. i figured that out but right now instead of using <div> elements inside the footer, i have been using the <ul> elements with a little change in CSS code.. and that works for me.. :)